# Spring and forms with select

Tags: java, spring, data-binding

I am using Spring to populate a  item in a form, using object passing between controller and views:

## Domain Objects

```
public class Client {
private String name;
private int id;
private Bar bar;
// getters and setters omitted
}


public class Bar {
private Integer id;
private String name;
// getters and setters omitted

}
```

## Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public String index(Model m) {
m.addAttribute("Client", new Client());
Bar o1 = new Bar();
o1.setName("n 1");
o1.setId(1);
Bar o2 = new Bar();
o2.setName("n 2");
o2.setId(2);
Bar o3 = new Bar();
o3.setName("n 3");
o3.setId(3);
Bar o4 = new Bar();
o4.setName("n 4");
o4.setId(4);
Bar o5 = new Bar();
o5.setName("n 5");
o5.setId(5);
List<Bar> orders = new ArrayList<Bar>();
orders.add(o1);
orders.add(o2);
orders.add(o3);
orders.add(o4);
orders.add(o5);
m.addAttribute("ordersList", orders);
return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/")
public String indexPost(@ModelAttribute("Client") Client g, BindingResult r) {
log.info(g.getId() + " " + g.getName());
log.info(g.getBar().getName());
return "index";
}
```

## View (index.jsp)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="Client">
<form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
<form:input path="name" />
<form:label path="id">Id</form:label>
<form:input path="id" />
<form:label path="orders">Order</form:label>
<form:select path="bar" items="${ordersList}" />    
<form:button>Insert</form:button>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Problem

When I fill out the form, and make the submit, the controller throw a NullPointerException on `log.info(g.getBar().getName());` 
I assume it is because getBar() returns `null`.
Where am I wrong with this data binding?

Comment: I can't see that you set the "bar" to the client anywhere... have you missed this bit?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you make an example?

Comment: First of all, what are your values when the select box is rendered? Is it an id or a primary key? Because, what I mean is when you post the form back to the server you have to fetch and set the actual "order" or in your case "bar" to your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a new `Client` object to the model, but that object is empty. Try first to create the full `Client` object and then set it to the model in the `index()` method.

**EDIT:**
So you need a property editor for that field. Adjust and add the method below to your controller:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Bar.class, "bar", new PropertyEditorSupport(Bar.class) {
        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            if(null != getValue()) {
                return ((Bar) getValue()).getId();
            } else {
                return StringUtils.EMPTY;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) {
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                setValue(UtilityClassUtils.getBarById(text));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What am I missing in the creation of the `Client` object?

Comment: You simply created a new `Client` object with `m.addAttribute("Client", new Client());` but all of its fields are null. So the call g.getBar() will return null, that why you got a NPE.

Comment: The call to `g.getBar()` is after `@ModelAttribute` (in the post method), and in that part of the code Spring should have filled the object with the corresponding values from the form.

Comment: I see, take a look my last edit. You need a property editor for the `bar` field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `form:select` tag is not properly defined. Can you try this?

```
 <form:select path="bar"> 
  <form:options items="${ordersList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
 </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your form will only post the IDs of the selected Bars back to your server side. So Spring won't be able to fill the Bar's name field automatically without additional work.

Secondly, to help Spring to convert ID to Bar or Bar to ID, you need to store your Bar objects somewhere. You can save the Bar in cache, session, database, or HTML Form's hidden inputs, etc. Let's say we store the Bar on the server side, and the store's interface is defined as below:

```
package com.example;

public interface BarStore {

    Bar getBar(Integer id);

    void putBar(Bar bar);

}
```

and store your Bar objects in your public String index(Model m) method as below:

```
...
@Autowired
private BarStore barStore;
...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public String index(Model m) {
    ...
    barStore.putBar(o1);
    barStore.putBar(o2);
    barStore.putBar(o3);
    barStore.putBar(o4);
    barStore.putBar(o5);
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can register some converters to convert Bar to ID and ID to Bar. Here is an example:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean;

@Configurable
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Autowired
    private BarStore barStore;

    public Converter<Bar, String> getBarToStringConverter() {
        return new Converter<Bar, String>() {
            public String convert(Bar bar) {
                return new StringBuilder().append(bar.getId()).append(' ').append(bar.getName()).toString();
            }
        };
    }

    public Converter<Integer, Bar> getIdToBarConverter() {
        return new Converter<Integer, Bar>() {
            public Bar convert(Integer id) {
                return barStore.getBar(id);
            }
        };
    }

    public Converter<String, Bar> getStringToBarConverter() {
        return new Converter<String, Bar>() {
            public Bar convert(String id) {
                return getObject().convert(getObject().convert(id, Integer.class), Bar.class);
            }
        };
    }

    public void installLabelConverters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(getBarToStringConverter());
        registry.addConverter(getIdToBarConverter());
        registry.addConverter(getStringToBarConverter());
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        installLabelConverters(getObject());
    }

}
```